# Кодировка из cp866 в cp1251

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

пишу конвертацию из кодировок, но столкнулся с проблемой. В приложении winForms выводит ошибку, что: No data is available for encoding 866. В консольном приложении нормально переводит, с чем это может быть связано?

```
string commandText = "SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(dbfFilePath);
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, connection))
{
    using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.GetString(3));
            byte[] newBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(866), bytes);
            string newStr = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(newBytes);
            textBox10.Text = newStr;
        }
    }
}
```

Строка подключения:

```
string connectionStringg = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(dbfFilePath) + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;charset=866";
```

Допольнительный код:

```
string dbfFilePath = "\\\\192.168.0.1\\Centrup\\BAZA\\OSDAL.DBF";
                    string connectionStringg = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Path.GetDirectoryName(dbfFilePath) + ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV";

                    using (OleDbConnection connection2 = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringg))
                    {
                        connection2.Open();

                        string commandText = "SELECT * FROM " + Path.GetFileName(dbfFilePath);
                        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, connection2))
                        {
                            using (OleDbDataReader reader1 = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                while (reader1.Read())
                                {
                                    string tn = removeZero(reader1.GetString(1));
                                    string str = reader1.GetString(3);
                                    
                                    DateTime date = reader1.GetDateTime(60);
                                    DateTime date1 = reader1.GetDateTime(12);

                                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
                                    byte[] newBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(866), bytes);
                                    string newStr = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(newBytes);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Тут бред какой-то написан. В `newBytes` у вас содержатся байты в кодировке 866. Далее вы пишете `GetEncoding(1251).GetString(newBytes)`, т. е. заявляете, что кодировка 1251.

Comment: Строки в дотнете имеют кодировку UTF-16. Тип `string` никак не может быть в какой-либо другой кодировке! Поэтому все эти ваши манипуляции бессмысленны! `textBox10.Text = reader.GetString(3)` - напишите так и этого достаточно.

Comment: Версия .NET какая?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, byte[] newBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(866), bytes); Если пишу textBox10.Text = reader.GetString(3), то строка вот такая получается: ├єъш°

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях. Редактируйте вопрос, нажав ссылку Править.

Comment: Если база читается в неверной кодировке, это значит что там данные сохранены в неверной кодировке, а не вы читаете их неправильно. Сохраняйте данные правильно и читаться они будут правильно без дополнительных костылей. Либо нужно верно задачть Connection String, покажите эту строку.

Comment: Как данные были занесены в таблицу? Покажите код. / Или вы используете уже готовую БД, которую заполнил кто-то другой?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Данные уже были занесены до меня, база не моя

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил.
Необходимо было прописать:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Comment: Это ничего не должно менять. Покажите больше кода, как сейчас сделали.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, код в теме